# Inject Vue component in HTML string

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a bunch of HTML strings that are imported from a file. 
They look like this:

```
<div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">{#}</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to inject a Vue component where I find the '{#}' sign.

I split the string

```
  data() {
    return {
      template: this.$props.data.template.split("{#}")
    };
  }
```

Then I placed them in the Vue template

```
<template>
  <div class="section">
    {{ template[0] }}
    <Subsection />
    {{ template[1] }}
  </div>
</template>
```

I need the values in the double curly brackets to be rendered as HTML. I tried with v-html but it doesn t work because of the wrapper that it generates around my code.

Comment: You can try `component.$el.outerHTML`